# setpgid(0, 0) fails when debugging with gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I'm trying to debug a linux user-space application, which creates a process group with `setpgid(0,0)`. When launched on terminal, it returns no error and work as expected. But when debugging with `gdb`, it returns `EPERM`.

I suspect that it is because the gdb attaches my process as a child. So it is not possible to set my process as parent with `setpgid(0,0)`. Is that correct? If so, isn't there a way to debug this case with `gdb`?

**Edit:**
Environment:
Ubuntu 12.04 Kernel 3.11.0-15-generic

Using the simple code below, if launched on terminal, I get `success!!`. If I debug with gdb (configured on Eclipse Luna), I get `setpgid: Operation not permitted`.

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int err = setpgid((pid_t)0, (pid_t) 0); 
    if (err < 0) 
        perror("setpgid"); 
    else
        printf("success!! \n");
    exit(err); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to  include some code that demonstrates the problem, as well as your environment? On Ubuntu 14.04.5, kernel  4.4.0-134-generic, with bash as my shell, this program that uses setpgid succeeds both under an interactive shell and under gdb: `#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int err = setpgid((pid_t)0, (pid_t) 0);
if (err < 0) perror("setpgid");
exit(err);
}
`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I get `EPERM` with your code as well (`setpgid: Operation not permitted`). Edited question with this code block and environment information. Thanks!

Comment: On my 12.04 system, it succeeds under gdb, but I'm running gdb in a terminal window. Eclipse may be setting things up differently. I'll see if I can find an eclipse that will work on 12.04 and look into it some more.